# Is the time lapse considered when estimating the age of the universe?

Tags: big-bang-theory, space-time, time-dilation

We say that our universe is 13.7 billion years ago. During the big bang, it doubled at least 90 times in trillionth of a second (as given [here](http://www.space.com/52-the-expanding-universe-from-the-big-bang-to-today.html)), and other topological statements.

The question is which time are we talking about. Is the time-lapse considered? If yes, how?

Comment: Which time-lapse are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As relativistic effects will cause clocks to run slower, a frame of reference must be chosen when considering the time of the "big bang". There is a natural and convenient choice of reference frame, based on the cosmic microwave background. The cosmic background appears to be extremely red-shifted light, indicating it is receding from us very fast, due to the expansion of the universe. If we choose a frame in which the CMB is receding equally fast in all directions, we have a convenient frame of reference. It is called the [Comoving frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance).

Now that we have a frame of reference, we can talk about time and distance in a way that all observers that share this frame can agree. In the comoving frame, the "big bang" occurred about 13.8 billion years ago.

To directly answer the question: The time measured is the time in the comoving frame and relativistic time dialations (time-lapse) are considered.